# An exception occurred when I tried to add more columns

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, abstracttablemodel

I'm making a GUI project, using MVC design pattern. This program contains JTable component, for which I've created a class MyTableModel which extends AbstractTableModel. As you can see below in MyModelClass, I have two methods *addColumn & removeColumn* , which have normally add/remove columns from table, until, I have come to the point, when I have to add 3 initial columns with 8 combinations into my constructor, and then try add/remove columns. [Here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/8zri.jpg/) you can see screenshot of program.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at mvc.TTableModel.getValueAt(TTableModel.java:79)
    at mvc.TTableModel.getColumnClass(TTableModel.java:84)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getColumnClass(JTable.java:2697)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getCellRenderer(JTable.java:5682)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2113)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(JViewport.java:731)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:887)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1063)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1512)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1443)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1236)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:784)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:757)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:706)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(RepaintManager.java:62)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1651)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91).
```

### Code snippet

```
public class TTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements ThreeInputConstants{

    private ArrayList<Object> columnList;
    private List<boolean[]> data;

    public TTableModel() {
        this.columnList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.data = new ArrayList<>();

        // adds p, q, r
        columnList.add(THREE_INPUT_TITLES[0]);
        columnList.add(THREE_INPUT_TITLES[1]);
        columnList.add(THREE_INPUT_TITLES[2]);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            boolean[] tempArray = new boolean[3];

            tempArray[0] = P_CONST[i];
            tempArray[1] = Q_CONST[i];
            tempArray[2] = R_CONST[i];

            data.add(i, tempArray);
        }

    }

    public void printListTemp() {
        System.out.println("Column list: " + columnList);
        System.out.println("Data: " + data);
    }

    public void addColumn(String header) {
        this.columnList.add(header);
        this.fireTableStructureChanged();
    }

    public void removeColumn(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex >= 0 && columnIndex < getColumnCount()) {
            this.columnList.remove(columnIndex + INPUT_COLUMN_COUNT);
            this.fireTableStructureChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return columnList.get(columnIndex).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
        //data[row][column] = value; 
        data.get(row)[column] = (boolean) value;
        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return data.get(row)[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
    }

}

public interface ThreeInputConstants {

    public static final Object THREE_INPUT_TITLES[] = {
            "p", "q", "r"
    };
    public static final boolean P_CONST[] = {
            true, true, true, true, 
            false, false, false, false
    };
    public static final boolean Q_CONST[] = {
            true, true, false, false, 
            true, true, false, false, 
    };
    public static final boolean R_CONST[] = {
            true, false, true, false, 
            true, false, true, false, 
    };
}
```

**UPDATE (FIXED):**

```
public void addColumn(String header) {
        this.columnList.add(header);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            List<Boolean> rowList = data.get(i);
            while (rowList.size() < columnList.size()) {
                rowList.add(false);
            }
        }
        this.fireTableStructureChanged();
    }
```

Comment: ALWAYS post the exact and complete stack trace of an exception.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also prefer `List<List<Boolean>>`.

Comment: I prefer that too, but I get this exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3`

Comment: List<List<Boolean>> won't solve his problem I think. The getValueAt method is doing an index-based get. Nothing stops someone providing an out of bound index.

Comment: Do you guys want me to upload project to mediafire, so that you can try out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the exception happens after you've called `addColumn()`. This method adds a new value to the columnList. So the number of column goes from 3 to 4. The table then asks the column class for the last column, and `getColumnClass()` returns the class of the 4th element of the first row. But the data still contains arrays of 3 elements, so the index 3 doesn't exist in the data.

The length of the column list and the length of every array in the data list should always match: `addColumn()` should replace each array in the data list by another one containing one more element. Or `getValueAt()` and the other methods should deal with it to return default values.

Comment: Yes, your guess is right, and I undertstand that. But what should I change/write ? What's 'ald' arraylist ?

Answer (score 2):

You are addding 8 entries to the data ArrayList, each entry contains an array of 3 element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    boolean[] tempArray = new boolean[3];

    tempArray[0] = P_CONST[i];
    tempArray[1] = Q_CONST[i];
    tempArray[2] = R_CONST[i];

    data.add(i, tempArray);
}
```

But the error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at
```

indicates you are trying to retrieve the element with index 3 which is the 4th element. Since your array only have 3 elements, it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception.

Check your client code that calls the getValueAt method and make sure it does not use index more than 2 for the column.

EDIT:

Try Change your getColumnCount and getRowCount to this:

```
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return data.size();        
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return columnList.size();
}
```

Comment: I understand that :), but how to avoid that, what should I add/change in code ?

Comment: if you have to use array as the internal structure, maybe expose a constant in the class thay specifies MAX_INDEX. And in your client code, use the constant to decide the upper bound of your loop etc. e.g.: for(int i = 0 ; i < TTableModel.MAX_LENGTH ; i++) {...}.

Comment: `Check your client code that calls the getValueAt method and make sure it does not use index more than 2 for the column.` What you mean by client code ? I haven't called anywhere getValueAt method yet.

Comment: that's intersting, wait a second :)

Comment: Nope, now it won't even run the program. Now I got exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3`...

Comment: Well. I think the problem is that it is the JTable that calls your method. The two method getColumnCount and getRowCount is used to tell the JTable how many rows and columns you have in your underlying data. The problem must be that your told it you have more than 3 row/column but you actually only have 3 row/column.